# Detect file type from NSURL

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurl

I have NSURL variable that contains different web links.I want to detect the type of the file that contains this link( if it contains any).
In example this is pdf file: https://vk.com/doc-105831417_445462965
How can I detect that this is PDF File or other type of file(ex. ZIP, doc) in code?
I have this code, but it's only working for files on the hardware:

```
CFStringRef fileExtension = (__bridge CFStringRef) [filePath pathExtension];
CFStringRef fileUTI = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, fileExtension, NULL);


if([self ifZip:filePath]){

    return ACFileTypeZIP;

}

if (UTTypeConformsTo(fileUTI, kUTTypeMovie)){

    return ACFileTypeZIP;

}else if (UTTypeConformsTo(fileUTI, kUTTypePDF)){

    return ACFileTypeDocument;

}else if (UTTypeConformsTo(fileUTI, kUTTypeImage)){

    return ACFileTypeImage;

}else if (UTTypeConformsTo(fileUTI, kUTTypeAudio)){

    return ACFileTypeAudio;

}

CFRelease(fileUTI);
```

Note ACFileType is my enum of types.ifZip is my method for detecting zip files:

```
-(BOOL)ifZip:(NSString*)path{


NSFileHandle *fh = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:path];
NSData *data = [fh readDataOfLength:4];
if ([data length] == 4) {
    const char *bytes = [data bytes];
    if (bytes[0] == 'P' && bytes[1] == 'K' && bytes[2] == 3 && bytes[3] == 4) {
        return YES;
    }
}

return NO;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should work:

```
NSString *extension = [url pathExtension];
```